# How to use multiple return values in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I'm need to use multiple return values from a function in HTML

Thats short version of the code. All imports are correct and if I return single value it works. Just don't know how to call both values in the HTML.

**In the view:**

```
def get_title_and_text():
    title = 'Some title'
    text = 'Some text'

    return title, text

def page():
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'get_title_and_text': get_title_and_text()}
```

**In the HTML**

```
<h3>{{ get_title_and_text.title }}</h3>
<h3>{{ get_title_and_text.text }}</h3>
```

I guess it's simple solution but I just could not find information about that matter

Comment: bro u just return a dict instead of 2 string in get_title_and_text(). this will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

There are two options: working with a subdictionary, or working with indices:

## Option 1: subdictionaries

```
def get_title_and_text():
    title = 'Some title'
    text = 'Some text'
    return {'title': title, 'text': text }
```

## Option 2: construct the context in the function

Another option is to construct the entire context in the function, in that case we work with:

```
def get_title_and_text():
    title = 'Some title'
    text = 'Some text'
    return {'title': title, 'text': text }
```

and call the function with:

```
def page():
    return render(request, 'page.html', get_title_and_text()}
```

in that case you can render the page with:

```
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
<h3>{{ text }}</h3>
```

## Option 3: working with indices

What you basically do is associating a 2-tuple with the `get_title_and_text` variable. You thus can access this with:

```
<h3>{{ get_title_and_text.0 }}</h3>
<h3>{{ get_title_and_text.1 }}</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the view:

```
def get_title_and_text():
    title = 'Some title'
    text = 'Some text'
    context = {
     'title' : title,
     'text' : text
    return context

def page():
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

in html

```
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
<h3>{{ text }}</h3>
```